# Find the order of infty

Tags: complex-analysis

> Classify the singularities (removable, pole, essential) of
> $f(z)=\dfrac{e^z}{1+z^2}$.

I already pointed out $z=\pm i$ are poles with order $1$.
Since $\lim\limits_{z\to\infty}f(z)=\infty$, I can conclude $\infty$ is also a pole point. But I don't know its order? Can someone help me to find the order of $\infty$? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure $\infty$ is a pole? Is every singularity a pole?

Comment: @GregMartin Why not? Since $\lim\limits_{z\to\infty}f(z)=\infty$

Comment: What is definition of singularity?

Comment: What is $\lim f(z)$ if $z \to \infty$ along the negative real axis?

Comment: @MartinR you misunderstood. $\infty$ means $+\infty$

Comment: I don't think so. If $f$ has a pole at infinity then $\lim_{z \to \infty} f(z) = \infty$ along *any* path.

Comment: @MartinR Since such lim doesn't exist, $\infty$ is essential singularity, right?